# Удалить папку с неизвестными правами

Tags: google-drive

Переустанавливал систему, на втором диске осталась папка Google Drive'a. Хочу ее удалить, но пишет, что нету прав. Поставил вроде как себя владельцем папки и всего, что в ней.Все равно не удаляет.  Как можно удалить такую нехорошую папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# lsof | grep <путь до папки>
```

Потом убить процесс, что её занимает.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузившись с Лайв-диска, например.